# what's the purpose of `impl Foo for Foo`?

Tags: object, rust, traits

I am looking for the answer why a sized trait is not object safe, for example:

```
trait Foo:Sized{}
```

Foo is not object safe.

I have read some posts about object safey, like [object-safety](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/) and [sizedness-in-rust](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/sizedness-in-rust.md#trait-objects). I find the deep reason is compiler automatically `impl Foo for Foo`.

I confuse why compiler do this and why this cause `Foo` not object safe?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ask yourself: Are trait objects sized? How *big* do you expect a `dyn Foo` to be? Not a `&dyn Foo`, but an actual *value* `dyn Foo`? Can we put a size on it?

Comment: Thank you very much. `dyn Foo` is unsized, so compiler cannot `impl Foo for Foo`, because only sized type can be implemented for Foo, so one cannot call Foo's methods on `dyn Foo`, so compiler refuse a trait to be a trait object I the trait require Sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`impl Foo for Foo` is the way to write in Rust "implement trait `Foo` for trait object `Foo`". A trait can be only object-safe if the trait object for this trait implements the trait. Obviously, there is no much sense having a trait object, that does not implement itself.

By specifying `trait Foo : Sized {}`, you require that all implementors of `Foo` must also implement `Sized`. But all trait objects in Rust are `?Sized`, meaning they can be unsized. Thus the trait object for type `Foo : Sized` cannot implement `Foo`, so you cannot write

```
impl Foo for Foo
```

or, in other words, the trait is not object safe.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I got the key point why it is important for a trait object to implement the trait itself after I read your answer. I can call the methods on a trait object of a trait only if the trait implemented for the trait object. So compiler implicitly implemented the trait for the trait object of itself as possible as it can. For a `trait Foo:Sized{}`, the trait can only be implemented for sized type, so compile cannot write `impl Foo for Foo`, so I cannot call Foo's methods on trait object Foo, so trait object Foo has no sense, so it is not object safe.